# How to find out what this code is doing in asp? New to asp

Tags: asp.net

I am running into an issue where I have to change the render value of the image caption.

Tried researching on w3schools but can't find the answer

```
<a href='/Product.aspx?ID=<%#Data.Binder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StyleGroup") %>'>
```

Comment: <a href='/Product.aspx?ID=<%#Data.Binder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StyleGroup") %>'>

Comment: `<a href='<%#Eval("StyleGroup","/Product.aspx?ID={0}") %>' runat="server">`